# Changing overmount to undermount sink

Tags: plumbing

[image]I currently have a sink that can be over or undermounted. It has been overmounted but I ordered quartz countertops and want a more finished look so changing to undermount. The man who measured for the countertops looked down below and thinks I could have problems with the drain being too high. He said I should look for a different disposal. Can anyone help me out on what I should be looking for. I don't want any last minute surprises. I found out today that the current sink will sit 1 1/4 inches lower than here. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the existing disposal/drain installation?

Comment: He was smart to call out the issue with the drain height.  I've seen a few issues with that, but we really would need more information (pictures) to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for your clear information. I went to Home Depot and even called Insinkerator and they all measure 6 1/4 so looks like I'll have to pay Plumbers to move the pipe. Darn. Was trying to avoid that.

Comment: You can also get a different sink which has a shallower bowl on the disposal side. Might cost less than moving the pipe, although you may want a deeper sink , something to think about.

Comment: I am going to keep the sink because that's all been taken into consideration for the countertops that are ready to go. From the top of my current disposal to the half way of the drain is 7 inches. If I take away 1 1/4 that puts me at 5 3/4. If I bought a new disposal it would be a 6 1/4 distance. You don't suppose they have any wiggle room for that

Comment: Looks real close, the seal on the white pipe is just below the nut. If you can slide the white pipe up a 1/2 that's all you need. You'll have to determine if it's going to hit the curved part of the black pipe. A glue trap (pipes are glued together) might give you that extra wiggle room. Ask your plumber about that before you move the pipe.

Comment: Thank you all! Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem you may not, it looks really close. What I would do is buy another disposal and if you don't need it return it. You need to find a disposal where the distance from the top flange of the disposal to the center of the drain hole is 1 1/4" less than what you have. The white pipe in the picture will not move up or down. The problem is because of the curve of the black pipe it does not look like that black pipe can be inserted 1 1/4" deeper into the white pipe.   [image: what to measure]